# VS Code erases the final part of my file without me notticing

Tags: python, c, visual-studio-code

When i'm coding through VSCode, sometimes the last part of my file either deletes or introduce red NULL characters. It's important because i can be in any place of the file, compile and suddenly I lost some lines...

I've being looking on Google but no one had this same error...

Example:

Before:

```
    print(qsel_nr(t, 0))
    print(qsel_nr(t, 1))
    print(qsel_nr(t, 2))
    print(qsel_nr(t, 7))
    print(qsel_nr(t, 8))
    print(qsel_nr(t, 9))
```

After:

```
    print(qsel_nr(t, 0))
    print(qsel_nr(t, 1))
    print(qsel_nr(t, 2))
    print(qsel_nr(t, 7))
    print(qse             <- deleted like this.
```

I've tried:

- Reinstalling VSCode.
- Reinstalling the extensions.
- Using Prettier.

But nothing happends.

Comment: Sounds like a hard drive or file system going bad.

Comment: are you writing to a file in your program?

Comment: Did you lose code after **saving the file**?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT It can be. I have the autosaving on...

Comment: @stark No... Is just a QuickSelect non recursive algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As someone suggested, the hard drive may have bad sectors.

If you use Windows, try storing the file on OneDrive and see, if the problem persists.

Alternatively you can try using a different text editor or IDE. VS Code has recently had many bugs including syntax highlighting breaking for me in Python, so try using PyCharm and see if the problem persists. If it does not, create an issue on vscode GitHub.

Comment: OneDrive caches to the files to the local hard drive.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try and see... It might be the Drive, but when I check it, no errores appear.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Well, i contacted with the VSCode GitHub and they let me a comand in order to search for the problem on one of the multiple extensión I have... I am still looking for the problem. I'll be update if I found It

Comment: Good luck on your problem search